# strtotime почему в ней нет минут?

Tags: php

Многие в своём коде используют модификатор времени **strtotime**.
Пример:

```
<?php
print(strtotime("+1 week 3 days 7 hours 5 seconds") . "<br>");
?>
```

Но почему в нём есть: *месяца, недели, месяцы, секунды, дни, года, название дней недели*, **но нет минут**?
Чем это обусловлено?
Почему такая дискриминация к этой мере исчисления времени?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы ошибаетесь. Они там есть :)

```
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time()) . '<br />';
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("+25 minutes")) . '<br />';
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("+1 week 3 days 7 hours 25 minutes 5 seconds")) . '<br />';
```

выдает

```
2015-10-14 14:15:39
2015-10-14 14:40:39
2015-10-24 21:40:44
```

Comment: Спасибо! Нашёл ошибку
Она была в "H:m" у меня.
`print date("H:m d/m/Y", strtotime("+1 hours 30 minutes"))." +1 час 30 минут";`